# How can i handle form data in a java httpserver server

Tags: java, handler, form-data

I'm hosting a http webserver in java(just localhost) to show an offline website(plain html). To send data back to java, a save button does a call with post/ form data using ajax.

I'm using com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

and would like to just being able to obtain the xml string in the handler.

I've tried several mapping functions, and examples found online. none which helped. They all found empty results so far.

My goal is to just select the xml variable, other variables do not matter. ( no iterative search / parser is required)

thanks in advance!
Erik

Javascript code:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
function saveFile() {

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      alert(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "/", true);
  //xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
  formData.append('xml', '<xml>some xml thing here</xml>');
  xhttp.send(formData);
}
</script>

java handler code:

private static void handleRequest(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
          String root = "TestPlanDesigner";

          URI uri = exchange.getRequestURI();
          //System.out.println(uri);
          //printRequestInfo(exchange);

          //if its the root, this means its posting the data
          if(uri.getPath().equals("/"))
          {
              if(exchange.getRequestMethod().equals("POST"))
              {
                  //handle the post request.
                  String response = "File saved successfully";
                  exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.getBytes().length);
                  OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody();
                  os.write(response.getBytes());
                  os.close();
              }
          }
```

Single line to select the xml form data in java, inside the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, it was in the body not the header.

in the handler:

```
String payloadrequest = getStringFromInputStream(exchange.getRequestBody());



private static String getStringFromInputStream(java.io.InputStream inputStream) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```